# Need solution to recover disk, can't mount a ddrescue partition image

Tags: mount, partition, data-recovery, ddrescue

I used ddrescue to build out a 910G disk partition (sdh4) from a 1Tb disk. The disk looks like this.

```
Warning: ignoring extra data in partition table 5
Warning: ignoring extra data in partition table 5
Warning: ignoring extra data in partition table 5
Warning: invalid flag 0x44dd of partition table 5 will be corrected by w(rite)

Disk /dev/sdh: 1000.2 GB, 1000204881920 bytes, 244190645 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 4096 = 4096 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk label type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x0cb2eaae

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdh1            2047     4196351    16777220    f  W95 Ext'd (LBA)
/dev/sdh2         4196352     5220351     4096000   ef  EFI (FAT-12/16/32)
/dev/sdh3   *     5220352     5482495     1048576    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sdh4         5482496  1953521663  7792156672    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sdh5   ?   402767664  3416680776 12055652452   9f  BSD/OS
```

I also captured the log. e.g. the command i ran to capture image

`ddrescue -v -n /dev/sdh4 recover.img recover.log`

I am not able to get this mounted. The error thats always returned:

`doesn't seem to have a valid NTFS.  Maybe the wrong device is used? Or the whole disk instead of a partition` 

mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/loop1, missing codepage or helper program, or other error`

I've tried using `mount`, `ntfs-3g`, `-o ro,loop`, even  by setting it as a loopback first them mounting that.  The error persists. I'm open to suggestions on how to mount it.

In an effort to try other solutions to get it mounted, maybe there is something in the partition table that is needed. So it got me to thinking;

> Maybe i can use the offset to get it mounted instead. Can i can use this recover.img file to fill in the rest of the drive over it, without having to rewrite the main 910GB partition in the image file? That will save 8 hours, and possibly the data before the drive becomes shrapnel. Can ddrescue handle it?

Is that possible, or will that mess up the img file?

e.g. What i'm thinking is this;
`ddrescue -v -n /dev/sdh recover.img recover.log`
And hoping it can fill in the other partitions to the existing ~910G file.

Any help is appreciated since this is important data.
Thanks in advance.

Edit: 
I just remembered, i couldnt even mount the partition directly, getting the same ntfs error.  I tried running smartctl on it, never seen this type of error from that.

````
Read Device Identity failed: scsi error unsupported field in scsi command

A mandatory SMART command failed: exiting. To continue, add one or more '-T permissive' options.```
````

Comment: Try `mkdir /mnt/rescue ; mount -o loop recover.img /mnt/rescue`.  You need to use a "loop device" as you are mounting a file, not a partition.

Comment: Thanks for response, I thought i mentioned i did that, but i realize i didnt post that output, i'll update the OP

Comment: First question. What does `file -s recover.img /dev/sdh4` say?

Comment: Thanks, it says `data` : `data` (data for both)

Comment: Not good! I would have expected it would have told you about the file system. OK question 2. Why were you running ddrescue? Were you starting to get disk errors reported (e.g. read errors or commands timing out) or was it you couldn't get to the data?

Comment: oh, the laptop it was mounted in was only opening to a backlit black screen, no boot.  but there is important data on there, so i wanted to ensure if it was due drive failure, that i image it asap, then extract it that way.  In fact, i got same error when mounting the drive itself.
Oh, just remembered getting smartctl error also, added that to OP.

Comment: FYI, i WAS able to do the trick i suggested above, where i took the partition image using the same log, but this time pointed testdisk to the full drive (`sda`), which completed to 100% making a complete image of the drive without having to start from scratch saving lots of time since that was only the last few % of the drive.  
Now im resorting to testdisk on the full disk image it to try to rebuild structure, and in a split screen scrubbing the data off a part4 image copy :-)

Comment: Imaging asap is a great plan. I am not sure that the `trick` you are employing is valid. I suggest that you try `cmp recover.img /dev/sdh` and see if it says nothing for say 10 seconds. Once you have the image then `testdisk` to recover the partition offsets is the next step. If you find that the recover.img is not a good match to the original data, you may be able to use 'dd' to create an recover2.img from the recover.img. The manual implies that you can use ddrescuelog to adjust the rescue.log, or create a new one, to save time, but this is outside my experience.

Comment: I got a `differ: byte 1, line 1`  does that mean they differ from the start?  i suspect maybe they differ when i went to recover partitions using testdisk, when they all didnt show up, so am taking a new full image using ddrescue(is that what you meant by dd?) easier so i can continue if needed with the log.  i totally should have done the first time. I recovered the data with photorec, but not wanting to go that route to dig it out, unless i have to, so i would like to use testdisk on the full image after its complete, thanks for that advice.

Comment: Yes, they differ from the start. What you have in the rescue.img is 700MB of the data from /dev/sdh4 at the start of the file, followed by the last 300MB of /dev/sdh (which happens to be the last 300MB of /dev/sdh4), or put it another way, not much use. If your new drive is a lot faster than the one you are trying to recover data from, you could in effect create 300MB of empty space that /dev/sdh1,2 and 3 could fit into, and then append the first 700MB of data from rescue.img. If your disk was dying I would certainly go that route, but as you old disk appears ok probably not worth the effort.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/102525/discussion-between-icarus-and-brian-thomas).